# Drawing lines in a DataGridView through rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-3.5

I'm trying to draw lines through rows in a DataGridView. The idea is to complete a Gantt Chart. By now I'm able to draw the bar column. But when a task is preceded by another, I need to draw the line connecting them.

This is where I am now:[image]

What I need is to draw the connector as, for example, "Tarea 6" and "Tarea 7" in the ellipse

[image]

Comment: How did you manage to draw the gantt red/blue bars ? What does prevent you to use the same method to draw the connectors ?

Comment: @digEmAll. All the bars are drawn in an unique cell, overriding the OnCellPaint. The red means that the task is delayed, the black means that is on time. The blue bars are tasks, the gray ones are groups, and the black one in the first row is the advance of all the project. The problem is that when I want to draw a line that stars in one row and ends in another, I only can draw the line for the first row, that is my drawing area.

Answer (score 1):

Try `RowPostPaint` event, for example :

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 20, e.RowBounds.Top + 6, 
                         e.RowBounds.Width, CInt(e.RowBounds.Height / 2));
```

Comment: Amen. The problem there is that the RowBounds are for just one row.

Comment: @Nane, You didn't get it, it's rendered for each row, so if you want to draw for specific rows so you call if(e.RowIndex == something)e.Graphics...otherwise do like my code without conditions

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it looks tricky. Please consider using [CellPaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting.aspx) for this. But I assume it can be pain to implement what you need.

Comment: I'm overriding the OnCellPaint to draw the bars already. Even if it seems a lot of cells, it's only one. The problem is that when I want to draw a line that stars in one row and ends in another, I only can draw the line for the first row, that is my drawing area.

Comment: What prevents from finding position of cell in next row and draw there?

Comment: Mmmmm. Probably I can draw on the Graphics object of the DataGridView instead of the cell. I will try tonight and let you know. Thanks Andriy

Comment: I guess you can. At least I remember I did this few years ago, with no issues. I'm just worrying if this can hurt your app performance (depends on how much drawing you have to do).